# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class do not have a property of the name return when returning HashMap in web service

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-ws

I have simple web service in glassfish 3.2.2 which only creates a file based on random `UUID` and saves it in the `docroot` folder then return result inside `HashMap`:

```
@WebService
public class Storage {
    @WebMethod
    public HashMap<String, String> store() {
        HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        File f = new File("../docroot/" + uuid + ".jpeg");
        if (f.exists()) {
            m.put("message", "file exists");
            m.put("file-name", uuid + ".jpeg");
            m.put("result", Integer.toString(-1));

            return m;
        }
        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(f);

            /* save some data in the file */

            fout.close();

            m.put("message", "file saved successfully");
            m.put("file-name", uuid + ".jpeg");
            m.put("result", Integer.toString(0));

            return m;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            m.put("message", "exception when creating file");
            m.put("file-name", uuid + ".jpeg");
            m.put("result", Integer.toString(-2));

            return m;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fout != null)
                    fout.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("error closing file with name: " + uuid);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

But i'm getting the following long exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class com.argengco.aggregate.jaxws.StoreResponse do not have a property of the name return
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointResponseMessageBuilder$DocLit.<init>(EndpointResponseMessageBuilder.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.createResponseMessageBuilder(TieHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.<init>(TieHandler.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:433)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:268)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:569)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:552)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:623)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WSServletContextListener.registerEndpoint(WSServletContextListener.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: return is not a valid property on class com.argengco.aggregate.jaxws.StoreResponse
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:981)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextWrapper.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBRIContextWrapper.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointResponseMessageBuilder$DocLit.<init>(EndpointResponseMessageBuilder.java:214)
```

I have to mention that when I return `int` instead of `HashMap<String, String>` it works fine and I can run the web service without any error.

I'm using java 7 in CentOS 6.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post for the answer: [JAX-WS Exception - "return is not a valid property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782797/jax-ws-exception-return-is-not-a-valid-property). You can't return HashMap, you need to create a wrapper for it.