# JAX-WS Exception - "return is not a valid property"

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I am new to JAX-WS, when I try to start this simple Web Service:

Interface:

```
package ws;

import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface IBasket {
    @WebMethod public abstract void addItem(int productId, int count);  
    @WebMethod public abstract HashMap<Integer, Integer> getBasketMap();
}
```

Implementing Class:

```
package model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import ws.IBasket;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "ws.IBasket")
public class Basket implements IBasket {

    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> basket;

    public Basket() {
        this.basket = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addItem(int productId, int count) {
        int currentCount = 0;
        if (basket.containsKey(productId)) {
            currentCount = basket.get(productId);
        }
        basket.put(productId, currentCount + count);
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<Integer, Integer> getBasketMap() {
        return basket;
    }
}
```

Publisher:

```
package endpoint;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import model.Basket;

public class WSPublisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/WS/Basket",new Basket());
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class ws.jaxws.GetBasketMapResponse do not have a property of the name return
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.EndpointResponseMessageBuilder$DocLit.<init>(EndpointResponseMessageBuilder.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.createResponseMessageBuilder(EndpointMethodHandler.java:191)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.<init>(EndpointMethodHandler.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.<init>(SEIInvokerTube.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:208)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:113)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:240)
    at endpoint.WSPublisher.main(WSPublisher.java:14)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: return is not a valid property on class ws.jaxws.GetBasketMapResponse
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:966)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.EndpointResponseMessageBuilder$DocLit.<init>(EndpointResponseMessageBuilder.java:193)
    ... 10 more
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I've found the solution for this problem, see:

[How can I pass in an array as a value into a PHP soapclient request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337901/how-can-i-pass-in-an-array-as-a-value-into-a-php-soapclient-request)

Its the same for HashMap return values. JAXB can't handle HashMaps as parameters/return values, maybe because they're generic.

So instead, we need a wrapper class for the HashMap<Integer, Integer>

```
public class HashMapWrapper {
    
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> basketMap;
    
    public HashMapWrapper(HashMap<Integer, Integer> basketMap) {
        this.setBasketMap(basketMap);
    }
```

and use this one as return value.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Metro as your JAX-WS provider? If so try setting the Document style as follows to RPC. This annotation should come after the @WebService annotation.;

```
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
```

Comment: To be honest, I've got no idea if I'm using Metro. All I have are these few POJO lines of code in my Eclipse JavaEE. But (style = Stlye.RPC) delivers me: 'Style cannot be resolved to a variable'